# How to Skip items efficiently from an IEnumerable which occasionally makes very slow requests?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have the following code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        foreach (var item in GetEnumerable().Skip(100))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
    }
    static IEnumerable<int> GetEnumerable(int? page = null, int limit = 10)
    {
        var currentPage = page ?? 1;
        while (true)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000); // emulates slow retrieval of a bunch of results
            for (int i = limit * (currentPage - 1); i < limit * currentPage; i++)
            {
                yield return i;
            }
            currentPage++;
        }
    }
}
```

I'd like to be able to use `.Skip(n)` to efficiently skip results I don't need. So, for example, if I use `Skip(100)` and each request retrieves 10 items, the first 10 requests should be skipped entirely.

Is there a pattern I can use to achieve this?

Comment: I could totally misunderstand what you're asking.. but if your code is taking too long.. perhaps you would think about removing `Thread.Sleep(1000);` from it?

Comment: You probably need some kind of delegate that will start your code in 10 seconds. Do you? Can you please clarify the question?

Comment: "I have to wait".. Do you mean that's a constraint that you have to adhere to, or that your code *at the moment* takes 10 sec to complete?

Comment: I cant remove Thread.Sleep. I want to remove evaulation of first 100 unnecessary elements.

Comment: This question actually makes sense, once you get past the somewhat hard-to-interpret initial version. I've edited it quite a bit to explain what is meant.

Comment: @romkyns +1 for your translation skills!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create your own `IEnumerable<int>` type and provide your own implementation of `Skip`:

```
public class PagedEnumerable : IEnumerable<int>
{
    private readonly int currentPage;
    private readonly int limit;

    public PagedEnumerable(int currentPage, int limit)
    {
        this.currentPage = currentPage;
        this.limit = limit;
    }

    public PagedEnumerable Skip(int count)
    {
        int pages = count / this.limit;
        return new PagedEnumerable(this.currentPage + pages, this.limit);
    }

    public IEnumerator<int> GetEnumerator()
    {
        int pageNo = this.currentPage;
        while (true)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            for (int i = this.limit * (pageNo - 1); i < (this.limit * pageNo); i++)
            {
                yield return i;
            }
            pageNo++;
        }
    }

    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

You can then replace your `GetEnumerable` with:

```
static PagedEnumerable GetEnumerable(int? page = null, int limit = 10)
{
    var currentPage = page ?? 1;
    return new PagedEnumerable(currentPage, limit);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, if you were to pass this around as `IEnumerable<int>` and someone called `.Skip` on that, the compiler will only notice the extension method, and thus it will still be slow (unless the LINQ `Skip` method actually checks whether the class implements `Skip`, but I highly doubt that).

Comment: @romkyns If you cast the item to `IEnumerable` it would indeed use the LINQ `Skip` extension, not this method.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do lazy evaluation of the "page", you shouldn't load it in the while loop.

Instead, what you could do, is return a lambda and return the page from that, something like this.

```
// return a list of funcs, where each one returns a loaded page
static IEnumerable<Func<int>> GetEnumerable(int? page = null, int limit = 10)
{
    var currentPage = page ?? 1;
    while (true)
    {
        for (int i = limit * (currentPage - 1); i < limit * currentPage; i++)
        {
            yield return () => {
               Thread.Sleep(1000);
               return i;
            };
        }
        currentPage++;
    }
}
```

And from the consumer thread, you simple execute the returned function to get the page.

```
foreach (var item in GetEnumarable().Skip(100).Take(10))
{
    Console.WriteLine(item());
}
```

Comment: I will think about this code, but i get data in batches. After Thread.Sleep(1000) I have 10 (=limit) items. And there is no yield return from lambda.

Comment: Hm, in that case your issue is a bit trickier.. You should be able to return a `Func<IEnumerable<int>>` as well, that just ignores the "load/sleep" if it's not needed. If you do that you'll have to take into account that it may not be 10 items per batch though, so you will have more than one item returned per yield.

Comment: I thought of this approach too, but it doesn't really mix well with the fact that the requests are batched.

Comment: @romkyns: No, I agree. This solution is not really applicable when you have things loaded in batches.. :-/

Answer (score 1):

Here’s my take at this. I build on Patrick’s idea with the lambda expressions, but I’ve fixed it so that it evaluates each batch only when needed, and no more than once.

```
static IEnumerable<Func<int>> GetEnumerable(int? page = null, int limit = 10)
{
    var currentPage = page ?? 1;
    while (true)
    {
        var thisPage = currentPage;
        List<int> thisPageResult = null;

        // Function that evaluates this batch and returns the result
        Func<List<int>> getPageResult = () =>
        {
            // only evaluate this batch once
            if (thisPageResult == null)
            {
                // slow retrieval of a bunch of results happens here
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                // store the result for future calls
                thisPageResult = Enumerable.Range(limit * (thisPage - 1), limit).ToList();
            }
            return thisPageResult;
        };

        for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++)
        {
            var j = i;
            // lazy: evaluate the batch only if requested by client code
            yield return () => getPageResult()[j];
        }

        currentPage++;
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    foreach (var func in GetEnumerable().Skip(100).Take(10))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(func());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make it the first parameter in the method, and don't give it a default value.

Comment: I want to get linq-compatible method

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully someone finds this approach helpful. The generic Lazy class in .NET is appropriate for this situation.

```
//Enumerable over all of the pages you want to possibly retrieve from:
IEnumerable<Lazy<Page>> pages = Enumerable
    .Range(0, 5)
    .Select(i => new Lazy<Page>(() => LoadPage(i)));
//Now if each page contains 10 items, and you want to skip the first
//35 items (and thus not load the first 3 pages), do this:
var items = pages
    .SelectMany(page => Enumerable
        .Range(0, 10)
        .Select(i => () => page.Value.GetItem(i)))
    .Skip(35) //any combination of Take, Skip, etc. could go here
    .Select(itemGetter => itemGetter())
    .ToList();
```